# Video Playing in Video Track 2 in old (2014.4.18.0) VLC Media Player - Set Video Track

Tags: c#, vlc, vlc.dotnet

I am currently using VlcControl (2014.4.18.0) to play the video in old 
    VLC Media player using rtsp Url in c# code

```
VlcControl _videoControl;
 String rtspUrl = networkUrl;
 var media = new LocationMedia(rtspUrl);
 media.AddOption("rtsp-tcp");
 _videoControl.Play(media);
```

The issue here is, the video is not playing in default Video Track 1 but 
it is playing in Video Track 2.

Is there any way to set the Video Track to 2?

Kindly let me know if any options available to set the video track and play.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `VideoTracksManagement` object that allows you to change the Video track.

Comment: Kindly can you give more information regarding this as i was unable to find it in this version of VLC (2.0 or 2014.4.18.0) dll .

Comment: Don't use libvlc 2, use libvlc 3 from nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows/. VideoTracksManagement is a Vlc.DotNet object.